How to fetch previous values of cells during Drag-Copy (AutoFill) event?
I've made a change log script that stores changes of every cell. It's working fine when I change value of one cell at the time. I have problem with drag-copy or whatever the event is called. My change log have a columns for values before the change and after the change. I don't have idea how I can fetch previous value during the Drag-Copy (AutoFill) event, because only when you release the mouse button the selection is made but with release new values are already there.
For example, let assume you have in column "A" 4 values
A1=1;
A2=2;
A3=3;
A4=4
If I drag-copy "1" from first cell to the last forth cell. I should see in the log
A2: current value =1 ; previous value = 2;
A3: current value =1 ; previous value = 3;
A4: current value =1 ; previous value = 4;
How to detect the autofill area for Previous Values before AutoFill populates cells with copied values?
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("Change Log") 'it returns in a sheet named "Change Log"
                                              
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 
 'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub      'not doing anything if a cell in A:A is changed
 If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("1:3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'Not doing anything if a cell is changed in first 3 rows
 'If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 8) = _
 '                                   Array("Date & Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To", "Sheet Name", "Column Name")

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                     'to optimize the code (make it faster)
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
 If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then
    TgValue = ExtractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.Value, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = False                               'avoiding to trigger the change event after Undo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = ExtractData(Target)                          'define the RangeValue
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                           'put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 Dim IdRow As String
 Dim customer As String
 Dim Markup As String
 Dim lsp As String
 Dim columnHeader As String
 For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
    If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
        columnHeader = Cells(4, Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Column).Value 'headers are on row 4
        lsp = Cells(Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Row, 5).Value
        customer = Cells(Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Row, 4).Value
     '   Markup = Cells(Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Row, 8).Value
        IdRow = Cells(Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Row, 1).Value
        sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 9).Value = _
                Array(Now, IdRow, UN, Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Row, RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), lsp, _
                                      Target.Parent.Name, columnHeader) ' if you want to see address of the changed cell leavr only RangeValues(r)(1)
    End If
 Next r
 
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long, arrInt, el
    For Each el In arr
        sh.Range(el(1)).Value = el(0)
    Next
End Sub
Function ExtractData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(rng.Cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the values and the cells address
            For i = 1 To a.Cells.count
                arr(count) = Array(a.Cells(i).Value, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    ExtractData = arr
End Function

excel table view

You cannot be helped without showing the code you use. I posted some time before a piece of code doing that... I suppose your code use the sheet Change event.

HI, could you paste a link to your solution or name of the post please.

This was happening some years before. I think it is easier for me to look into my testing environment, I will maybe find it and post. I never needed it. It was a kind of challenge to solve somebody question...  If I remember well, I did not use the second event. I used to place the initial values in a jagged array (after UnDo) and changed valued in another one, using them to correctly log the changes, even for discontinuous ranges.

Please, try the next code. Adapt it for your needs.
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 'the array to keep Target values (before UnDo)
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Sheets("LOG_") 'it returns in a sheet named "LOG_"
                                              'Please, adapt the code, or name a sheet as necessary for the code to work
 Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 
 'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub      'not doing anything if a cell in A:A is changed
 'If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("1:2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'Not doing anything if a cell is changed in first two rows
  'sh.Unprotect "" 'use here your real password, if any
 If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 6) = _
                                     Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To", "Sheet Name")

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                     'to optimize the code (make it faster)
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
 Dim strDelInsert As String
 If Target.Columns.count = Me.Columns.count Then
    'to make code 'understanding' deletion versus insertion:
    strDelInsert = IIf(WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target) > 0, "Delete row(s): ", "Inserted row(s): ")
     If Target.rows.count > 1 Then
        MsgBox "It deals with only one row insertion/deletion..."
        Application.EnableEvents = False
         Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True: Exit Sub
     End If
     sh.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).value = _
             Array(Now, UN, strDelInsert & Target.address, , , Me.name): Exit Sub
 ElseIf Target.cells.count > 1 Then
    TgValue = ExtractData(Target)
 Else
    TgValue = Array(Array(Target.value, Target.address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or as a string for a single cell)
    boolOne = True
 End If
 Application.EnableEvents = False                               'avoiding to trigger the change event after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = ExtractData(Target)                          'define the RangeValue
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                           'put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
 For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
    If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
        'columnHeader = cells(1, Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Column).value
        'rowHeader = Range("A" & Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).row).value
        sh.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).value = _
                Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(r)(1), RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), _
                                      Target.Parent.name, rowHeader, columnHeader)
    End If
 Next r
 
 'sh.Protect ""
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
    Dim i As Long, arrInt, el
    For Each el In arr
        sh.Range(el(1)).value = el(0)
    Next
End Sub
Function ExtractData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(rng.cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the values and the cells address
            For i = 1 To a.cells.count
                arr(count) = Array(a.cells(i).value, a.cells(i).address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
            Next
    Next
    ExtractData = arr
End Function


@Shoti Didn't the code I supplied do what you need? Is it something in the code not clear enough?

This is briliant !!! It works even for copy-paste rows. I have 2 questions:
1.If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select - is it any reason behind it except cosmetics?
2. How to change 3rd column "RangeValues(r)(1)" to show only row number?

@Shoti 1. If I remember well, so was the requirement in the question I answer to. If one cell is changed, cell selection to jump a row down, as happening after pressing Enter.  2. RangeValues(r)(1) keeps the changed cell address.  It is necessary to have a reference when putDataBack (the same function is used to memorize the initial values...). If you really do not need to record the address of the changed cell, you can use Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Row, but I must confess that it is difficult for me to understand why, in which circumstances to need that...

Well, it is more convienent to have a column name and a row number instead cell address. Let assume you have a big worksheet with 100 columns address D77 will says nothing. Anyway - I'am really gratefull for your solution sir., It helped me a lot.

@Shoti In case of 100 columns, changing 4 different cells you will have D77, D78, E77 and D78. What relevance will have row 77 twice and the same for row 78? You asked only about the row number and you can see above how to handle it. Of course, you can proceed the same for column (Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Column). Even if, you have both these pieces of information in D77. Probably, I am missing something or you did not correctly/clearly expressed your need...

Yes, probably I did not express myself clear enough. First of all I have made all changes I wanted so no further support is needed. I just said that from the user point of view showing address of changed cell as coordinates like ZZ99 (extreme example on purpose) are not very usefull as you cannot memorize many column names. So I prefer to see in separate columns just row number and column name - with that the user do not need to even leave the change log tab for checking what sort of data (information) was changed in the data tab. Hope it's clear now.

@Shoti I cannot understand what you mean, sorry. But if you solved the issue, I do not have any problem with your approach. I only tried helping...

And you did. :) The only thing the solution is missing to perfection is to catch deletation of entire row but I can live with that.

@Shoti I think the code (as it is), I mean the Change event already catches the row deletion. The code has not been designed for such a purpose, but how would you like it to return in such a case. I think I can adapt it to 'understand' it is a matter of deletion and I cam adapt it to treat only the cells on the respective row from the sheet used range, but how to return in order to look convenient? There are already columns with their headers. How to adapt the return for such a case. But something concrete, not only rows. How to "memorize many column names" and changed cells values?

Hi @FanuDuru, I've checked couple of times and code doesn't catch the deletion. I've also edited the post and paste current state of the code and a link to the image of my table how it should look like in the log after delation. I believe the best would be to have single row with information who and when deleted the row on which sheet, the row ID, and I have a column called Markup for comments it would be really cool to have a fixed text ( "delation of:" + customer ) I have in 4th column so Customer= Cells(Range(RangeValues(r)(1)).Row, 5).Value

@Shoti When I said "event already catches the row deletion" I did not mean that the deletion is recorded. It means that the event is triggered! It can be recorded if I will adapt the code, but I specifically asked you how would you like it to return and I still do not know how to do it. The code places the data to be returned in an array and drop it in some specific columns having their clear meaning... "a single row" does not say too much. Do you only want it to write "Row x deleted", without values of the cells on the respective row, having data, which disappeared?

Hi @FaneDuru In my initial post under the code there is a link to screenshot "excel table view" I put on it which columns should remain empty and which should be populated. In addition to the photo it would be good to see in "Markup" field sentence ( "delation of:" + customer name ) that I store in Customer String variable

Hi@FaneDuru are you still willing to solve row deletion issue I have. I only want it to write "Row x deleted", without values of the cells on the respective row, having data, which disappeared

@Shoti Since I did not understand anything from the mentioned link, related to deletion, I did not do anything... I will adapt it to also catch row(s) deletion. And also insertion.

@Shoti Please, test the updated code and send some feedback. It is able (as it is) to trigger only deletion or insertion of a single row and not allows more than one. To keep track of more rows is a little more complicated and I do not have time for such a task.
